# Merged / Closed (exact duplicates)

Tags: discussion

For example [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2530/ive-notice-suns-jdk-is-not-available-for-ubuntu-10-04) was "merged", and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7912/gnome-doesnt-recognize-in-10-10-closed) was "closed". What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question was merged because it contained several viable answers that contributed to the question it duplicated. It was first closed as off-topic then the answers were merged into its duplicate. Whereas the second question doesn't contain any answers which would be of value to the question it duplicates. Therefore a merge wasn't performed.